# cli commands not working asterisk on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, asterisk

I installed VMware and then Ubuntu. I am running asterisk on top of it.

I started the asterisk server successfully by following a tutorial. After making few changes into the `sip.conf`, I want to reload the the process so it pick up the changes. So I ran

```
sip reload
```

and nothing happens.

Neither the commands to restart the asterisk server work actually the commands do not exists. Can some please throw light or point to right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you in Asterisk CLI?

```
asterisk -r
asterisk*CLI>sip reload
```

Comment: thanks for the reply PAUL yes im in asterisk cli and i do issue the sip reload command but nothing happens

Comment: Try starting CLI with 'asterisk -vvvvvr' for debugging messages. 

Also, stupid question, are you starting it with sudo? Never used ubuntu with asterisk.

Comment: i have to test it on vmware and thats why unbuntu running on windows 7 vmware and asterisk inside it

Comment: i have already started asterisk with -vvvvvc option and now i can't even shut it down

Comment: sudo killall -9 asterisk

Answer (score 1):

Command to restart asterisk is

```
asterisk -rx "core restart now"
```

IF that not work, probably your asterisk core is hangs.